# How to reduce a covariance matrix after clustering?

Tags: clustering, covariance-matrix

I have an `N = 100` covariance matrix. I am clustering the covariance matrix say into `5 clusters`.

How can I compute the reduced covariance matrix of weighted cluster means which has `dimension = 5x5?`

In particular, I am working on an algorithm for financial asset allocation. This algorithm first performs an allocation on clustered returns. Initially, I have 100 stocks to allocate, but after this step, I am left with only 5 clusters. In the second and last step of the allocation, I would like to run a quadratic optimization that minimizes the portfolio variance. Nevertheless, for doing so, I would need to reduce the covariance matrix to a dimension equal to the number of clusters.

Any hint on how to achieve this?

Comment: Please explain what the "reduced covariance matrix" might be.  Could it be the covariance matrix for the five cluster means? For some weighted cluster means? Cluster sums? Something else?

Comment: It would be for weighted cluster means

Comment: What are the weights?

Comment: Let's say that I want to equally weight 5 clusters

Comment: For any fixed set of weights (assigned to all 100 stocks), that's just a calculation based directly on the definition of covariance: is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Okay, so you would suggest something like t(w) dot COV dot w, right? Then in this case, if I need to first estimate the clustered weights and mean for each period, which means that I would calculate the reduced covariance matrix with look-ahead-bias?